# Invocationtargetexception in the AsyncTask when using the dialog dismiss function

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the question about using the AsyncTask with the ProgressDialog.There is the exception after I call the dismiss method. I have find many related questions about this and The answer is "Put it in PostExecute()". However it does not work...

```
public class Testing2 extends Activity {

private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

private ProgressBar mProgress;
private int mProgressStatus = 0;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.done);

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

    new Testing().execute(1,2,3);


}
private class Testing extends  AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

       protected void onPreExecute()
       {
           ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
               dialog.setMessage("dasdasd");
               dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
               dialog.setCancelable(false);
               dialog.show();

       }
     protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... urls) {

           Integer totalSize = 1;

           return totalSize;
       }

       protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

       }

       protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
           dialog.dismiss();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning ProgressDialog to a local variable and not to the field `dialog`
So instead of

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

use

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(Testing2.this);
```

If you are not doing much in doinbackground, i doubt the progressbar will show up. If you want to test the functionality, atleast put a sleep call for 2 seconds in doinbackground